# Why is mat-table filtering not working on particular column

Tags: angular, datasource, angular-material-table

I currently do not understand why custom filtering does not work on the first two columns: student_id and student_name.

Surprisingly, filtering works on other columns (CAs).

I appreciate your help.

**Model is**:

```js
export class CassData {
    enroll_id: string;
    student_id: string;
    student_name: string;
    ca1: number;
    ca2: number;
    ca3: number;
    exam: number;
    total: number;

    static asFormGroup(cass: CassData): FormGroup {
        const fg = new FormGroup({
            enroll_id: new FormControl(cass.enroll_id),
            student_id: new FormControl(cass.student_id),
            student_name: new FormControl(cass.student_name),
            ca1: new FormControl(cass.ca1),
            ca2: new FormControl(cass.ca2),
            ca3: new FormControl(cass.ca3),
            exam: new FormControl(cass.exam),
            total: new FormControl(cass.total)
        });
        return fg;
    }
}
```

**cass.component.ts file**

```js
export class CassComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['student_id', 'student_name', 'ca1', 'ca2', 'ca3', 'exam', 
   'total', 'delete'];

  constructor(private _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, 
            private _formBuilder: UntypedFormBuilder,
            private _cassService: CassService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Create the form
    this.assessmentForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      term: [''],
      subject_code: [''],
      class_name: [''],
      cass: this._formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }

  getCassData(): void {

    this.isLoading = true;
    
    let sch_code = this.sch_code;
    let data = this.assessmentForm.getRawValue();

    this._cassService.getCassAsFormArray(sch_code, data).subscribe(cass => {

      if (cass.length > 0) {
        
        this.assessmentForm.setControl('cass', cass);

        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource((this.assessmentForm.get('cass') as FormArray).controls);

        this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: FormGroup, filter: string) => {
          return Object.values(data.controls).some(x => x.value == filter);
        };

        this.assessmentList = true;

        this.dataSource.sort = this._sort;
        this.isLoading = false;
      } 
      else {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.assessmentList = false;
      }

      // Mark for check
      this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();

    });
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.toLowerCase();
  }

}
```

**cass.component.html**

```html
<div class="w-full">
  <form [formGroup]="assessmentForm">
   <button 
    (click)="getCassData()"
    mat-stroked-button>
    <span class="ml-1">Load Data</span>
   </button>
   <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" 
   [autocomplete]="'off'" 
   [placeholder]="'Search students'"
   [disabled]="!assessmentList" #searchField>
  </form>
  
  <ng-container *ngIf="assessmentList; else noData">
    <ng-container formArrayName="cass">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
            <!-- ID Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="student_id">
                <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    {{element.get('student_id').value}}
                </td>
            </ng-container>
                            
            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="student_name">
                <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    {{element.get('student_name').value}}
                </td>
            </ng-container>
                            
            <!-- CA1 Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="ca1">
                <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> CA1 (10%)</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [formGroup]="element">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input type="number" formControlName="ca1" matInput>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
                            
            <!-- CA2 Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="ca2">
                <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> CA2 (10%)</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [formGroup]="element">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input type="number" formControlName="ca2" matInput>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
            
            ...
            
        </table>
      </ng-container>
   </ng-container>

</div>
```

[When filtering CA (type: number) columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCKgA.png)

[When filtering name or id (type: string) columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ohl1.png)

Comment: since your filter-condition is  `x.value == filter` it will of course not find partial matches in a string

Comment: @TmTron, please what should the filter-condition be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I thank those who contributed to getting the answer to my question.

After checking what `@TmTron` said about filtering condition, and the test provided by `@Adonsio`, I eventually got it working using this:

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: FormGroup, filter: string) => {
   return Object.values(data.controls).some(x => x.value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filter.toString().toLowerCase()));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is your wanted result but if also partial matches should be includes like @TmTron mentioned. Then you could check if the value includes the filter.

```js
const controls = {
  student_name: {value: "test123"},
  student_id: {value: "123test"},
}
const filter = "test"
console.log(Object.values(controls).some(x => x.value.includes(filter)));
```

Comment: When I run `console.log(Object.values(data.controls).some(x => x.value.includes(filter)));` I got `TypeError: x.value.includes is not a function`